# First row of CSV ignored, csv.reader() | Menus and Lists - Accessing different rows in a CSV from a simple input() menu and loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

lol.txt is as follows:

```
1,2,3\n
\n
4,5,6\n
\n
AwesomeSauce,12.3,10\n
```

The code I'm using:

```
import csv

NumberAdult = input("Please enter the number of adults: ")
NumberAdult = int(NumberAdult)
NumberChild = input("Please enter the number of children: ")
NumberChild = int(NumberChild)
n = 0
with open ("lol.txt",'rt', newline = '\n') as f:
    csv_r = (line for line in csv.reader(f) if line)
    for row in csv_r:
        entries = [(name, float(price1), float(price2)) for name, price1, price2 in csv_r]
        for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
            price1 = float(entry[1])
            price2 = float(entry[2])
            print ("%i. %17s - %5.2f / %5.2f" % (index, entry[0], price1, price2))

choice = int(input("Which package would you like?: "))

packageChoice = (entries[choice])
for row in packageChoice:
    name = entry[0]
    AdultPrice = float(entry[1])
    ChildPrice = float(entry[2])

price = AdultPrice*NumberAdult + ChildPrice*NumberChild

print(name, price)
```

The output:

> Please enter the number of adults: 2
>      Please enter the number of children: 1
>      0.                 4 -  5.00 /  6.00
>      1.      AwesomeSauce - 12.30 / 10.00
>      Which package would you like?: 1
>      AwesomeSauce 34.6

What this means is that it is ignoring the first line of lol.txt - `1,2,3\n` - because `csv.reader()` appears to treat this row as fieldnames rather than data.

Is there a way around this? Use `csv.dictreader()` or something to assign field names independent of the file itself?

Edit: Nevermind `csv.reader()`, it doesn't treat them as field names. So it looks like the problem is in this section:

```
with open ("lol.txt",'rt', newline = '\n') as f:
    csv_r = (line for line in csv.reader(f) if line)
    for row in csv_r:
```

Now, I can't figure out what to do here - this is the closest I've gotten the script to working. Any tips, search terms, anything?

Final edit:
Nevermind, it all works now! I had a loop I forgot about:

```
for row in csv_r:
   entries = [(name, float(price1), float(price2)) for name, price1, price2 in csv_r]
```

Which caused it to skip the first line.
Thanks to dash from #python on freenode for making me look at that line again!

New Problem:

```
import csv

NumberAdult = input("Please enter the number of adults: ")
NumberAdult = int(NumberAdult)
NumberChild = input("Please enter the number of children: ")
NumberChild = int(NumberChild)
n = 0
with open ("lol.txt",'rt', newline = '\n') as f:
    csv_r = (line for line in csv.reader(f) if line)
    entries = [(name, float(price1), float(price2)) for name, price1, price2 in csv_r]
    for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
        price1 = float(entry[1])
        price2 = float(entry[2])
        print ("%i. %17s - %5.2f / %5.2f" % (index, entry[0], price1, price2))

choice = int(input("Which package would you like?: "))

packageChoice = (entries[choice])
for row in packageChoice:
    name = entry[0]
    AdultPrice = float(entry[1])
    ChildPrice = float(entry[2])

price = AdultPrice*NumberAdult + ChildPrice*NumberChild

print(name, price)
```

The only 'option' (regardless of what you input as your option) is 2., as it is the last line put through the list `entries`.

```
>>>
Please enter the number of adults: 2
Please enter the number of children: 1
0.                 1 -  2.00 /  3.00
1.                 4 -  5.00 /  6.00
2.      AwesomeSauce - 12.30 / 10.00
Which package would you like?: 1
AwesomeSauce 34.6
>>>
```

Now, I'm fairly sure the problem is in here:

```
csv_r = (line for line in csv.reader(f) if line)
entries = [(name, float(price1), float(price2)) for name, price1, price2 in csv_r]
for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
```

Or, I should do another section similar to this for the results of the menu, I'm not sure.
I'm going to work on implementing both to try troubleshoot it.

Comment: Your code style is quite different from the standard Python code style as defined in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I recommend that you follow it; it makes many things much easier (and more consistent).

Comment: While we're at it, I suggest that you read Dan Goodger's [*Code like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python*](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) in addition to PEP 8.

Comment: `I had a loop I forgot about:`... This is why we avoid mutating global variables. You can modify the global variable at one point, forget you've modified it, and then it comes back to shoot you in the foot later.

Answer (score 3):

Remarks that are too long to go in comments;

`csv.reader()` does not treat the first row as headers (only `DictReader` has that behaviour.) Try inserting some print statements for debugging - it would be helpful to see what `csv_r` contains.

---

```
csv_r = (line for line in csv.reader(f) if line)
```

Are you sure you didn't mean to use square brackets for a list expression, instead of parens for a generator expression?

---

```
for row in csv_r:
        entries = [(name, float(price1), float(price2)) for name, price1, price2 in csv_r]
```

Are you sure you want to materialise the list `entries` once for EVERY row in `csv_r`? Surely you only need to do this once?

---

Comment: I think the generator expression makes perfect sense here. Otherwise, I fully agree.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the csv module wrongly.
It returns a generator, so subsequent calls return more lines.

Effectively you are generating a list of identical generators.

You seem to convert/check your data twice

you are looping over the rows in csv_r, then usign a list comprehension to do the same, that is reduntant.

Here is a simplified version

```
import csv

NumberAdult = input("Please enter the number of adults: ")
NumberAdult = int(NumberAdult)

NumberChild = input("Please enter the number of children: ")
NumberChild = int(NumberChild)
n = 0

with open ("lol.txt") as f:
    csv_r = csv.reader(f)
    entries=[]
    for row in csv_r:
        #TODO:do checks here
        entries.append((row[0], float(row[1]), float(row[2])))

for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
    price1 = entry[1]  #do you need this?
    price2 = entry[2]  #do you need this?
    print ("%i. %17s - %5.2f / %5.2f" % (index, entry[0], price1, price2))

choice = int(input("Which package would you like?: "))
packageChoice = (entries[choice])
for row in packageChoice:
    name = entry[0]
    AdultPrice = float(entry[1])
    ChildPrice = float(entry[2]) 
price = AdultPrice*NumberAdult + ChildPrice*NumberChild
print(name, price)
```